# How can I make it to responsive body background image without using fixed?

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to make my body background image to be responsive in any mobile view? Especially when the height is `412x980`? I know how to use some proper background cover

```
body {
  background: url(../../something.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

But I wanted to not use `fixed` because I need to stay all elements on that background image.

## EDIT:

After using @VIKESIR provided code, I still getting `whitespace`    after trying to resizing every mobile views, I got the mobile view   sizes [here](https://mediag.com/blog/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/). Something like this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
       * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  body {
    background: url(https://www.psdstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/copyright-free-images-750x420.jpg) no-repeat center cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
 }
    }
```

```html
<body></body>
```

and this is what I meant still getting a `whitespace` after using the provided code.[image: Looks like this]

Comment: Provide height to your body tag.

Comment: Add HTML code also, in snippet. I want to see your title tag.

Comment: Try new code, and check with resize window screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default body height is nothing, so we need to define height.
Here is some css except body tag in last one, that you can configure in every style.css when you create new stylesheet.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #fa0;
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.title h1 {
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    body {
        background: url(https://www.psdstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/copyright-free-images-750x420.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="title">
    <h1>TESTING<br>TESTING TESTING</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can put it on the `@media screen only` right? Since I only need to use `body background` for mobile

Comment: yes bro, If you need this in only mobile view. Add in @media

Comment: I have one more question, since you provide a responsive background image, when I got any whitespace that means i need to readjust the texts?

Comment: You will never get whitespace because our background has cover size. So when extra content will be there, it will adjust width and height according to that.

Comment: Weird, because I got an extra whitespace

Comment: Where? can you explain in detail. I will fix that one.

Comment: Copy and add in top of css -> *{} and body,html{} also.

Comment: See my edit post if it answered your question

Comment: It actually works, I think there's a problem of capability of getting the width of `360x640` but overall its working fine. Thanks!